# Pass Variable to Python in Bash Script

Tags: python, bash, function

I'm trying to transfer a variable in a bash-script to an embedded python-function. A minimal example of the script I'm using is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash

function python_print() {
PYTHON_ARG="$1" python - <<END
import os
p = str(os.environ['PYTHON_ARG'])
print('The Variable is ' + p)
END
}

DIRIN=$1
FULLPATH=$ realpath $OUTFILE
python_print $FULLPATH
```

Running the script gives me: "The variable is "; so it seems the argument FULLPATH is not transfered to the function. The strange thing is, the code works if "$FULLPATH" is replaced either with "$1", "$DIRIN" or any hardcoded string.
Where is my mistake? I'm grateful for any advice!

Comment: But where is `OUTFILE` ever defined?

Comment: If instead of `python_print $FULLPATH` you did `echo $FULLPATH` does it print the value you expect? I suspect the line above is meant to be `FULLPATH=$(realpath $OUTFILE)`

Comment: @Bailey Parker: My mistake, I tried to post a minimal example of my original script, so I accidently deleted the line "OUTFILE=$2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in python_print function (note that `function` keyword is redundant with `()`). but in FULLPATH assignment and function call

correct syntax

```
FULLPATH=$(realpath "$OUTFILE")
python_print "$FULLPATH"
```

- no space between `=` and value in assignment
- double quotes around variable expansion in function call
- expansion must be double quoted except

  - if $ appears just after = in assignment
  - conditions between double brackets `[[` `]]`

note that

```
FULLPATH=$ realpath $OUTFILE
```

is not affecting FULLPATH in current shell process environment, it just sets FULLPATH to `$` to realpath execution process environment also output is not captured.

Answer (score 0):

Just either:

- `export` your bash variable so it is available in `os.environ`
- or use positional parameters and read it from `sys.argv`